# How can I navigate the call stack in Visual Studio using just the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, callstack

My current solution is to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, which navigates via the menus to the call stack, and then I can use the arrows to navigate. But once I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a particular frame, I have to repeat again.

Is there a more fluid way to navigate the call stack with just my keyboard?

ReSharper oriented answers are OK for me if you have one!

Answer (score 25):

I use the VS2010 default keyboard mapping scheme and by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> brings up the call stack window in which I can use the arrow keys to navigate.

The macro name is `Debug.CallStack`

Comment: It has a non-developer configuration?

Comment: @HansPassant: I have edited my answer, however, I do remember VS prompting me at some pt. (first run?) to pick if I was primarily a C++ dev., web dev., and couple other options so that it could map shortcuts. I must have been thinking of a previous version of VS.

Comment: I assigned Debug.CallStack to a keyboard shortcut already and it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @joshcomley: using Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard to assign the shortcut, select Global for 'Use new shortcut in:'. Also, you can use this dialog to check to see if your key combo works and to check if you have a conflict (example, another macro assigned to the shortcut at the same scope).

Comment: @HansPassant: `ctrl+alt+c` is assigned to Callstack in the default General Development scheme.

Comment: @RogerStewart - that's exactly what I did!

Comment: Unfortunately after pressing enter the focus is lost

Answer (score 4):

Here is a dorky [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script that will navigate up and down the call stack using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>NumPadUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>NumPadDown</kbd>.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; Allow for partial matches in window titles
#IfWinActive, (Debugging) ; Only work while VS is debugging
  ^!Numpad2:: ; Navigate down Call Stack in Visual Studio
    Send ^!c
    Send {Down}
    Send {Enter}
  return
  ^!Numpad8:: ; Navigate up Call Stack in Visual Studio
    Send ^!c
    Send {Up}
    Send {Enter}
  return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: For the first first time a small timeout is needed for the popup window, if it's docked:
Send ^!c
Sleep, 200
Send {Down}

Answer (score 3):

Call Stack view in Visual Studio can be brought up with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. That allows navigating the stack with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> as well as performing "Switch To Frame" action with <kbd>Enter⏎</kbd>.

Unfortunately, switching to a frame moves focus to the editor window, so the above sequence of actions has to be done again if you want to switch to another frame.