# Keys to step back all the debugging points

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

i want to know the key steps to step back while debugging c sharp code in vs 2017.
Example, i put a break point at a function. while debugging, the programme hits at this break point. But from that break point, how i can jump back to all the invoking points in the code ? Something like 'Ctrl' and '-' key. I want to know from where this is called. Track back like that.

Comment: Look at the call stack window and click anyone of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is called the [*Call Stack*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/viewing-the-call-stack-in-visual-studio).

Imagine we have this program:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static int something;
    public static void Main()
    {
        One();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Three()
    {
        something = 3;
        Four();
    }

    private static void Four()
    {
        something = 4;
    }

    private static void Two()
    {
        something = 2;
        Three();
    }

    private static void One()
    {
        something = 1;
        Two();
    }
}
```

Imagine we have a breakpoint in `Four()` and the debugger stops there, if we view the call stack window, it will look like this:

[image]

We can click and go to any point in the call stack history. The best part is, when you click `One()`, it will show the the value `something` had at that point in the call stack; so although we are in `Four()` and the value of `something` is 4, if you jump to `One()`, the value will show as zero.

For keyboard shortcuts, please refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618397/how-can-i-navigate-the-call-stack-in-visual-studio-using-just-the-keyboard).

Comment: I expected keyboard keys like "Ctrl + -" for stepping back code debugging.